# Tomcat6w.exe Vs javaw.exe - tomcat instance

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, javaw

Under service manager (`services.msc`) there is an executable `tomcat6w.exe`

Each tomcat instance launched from `eclipse IDE` & `services.msc` is seen as executable `javaw.exe`

### [image]

Despite the tomcat instance is stopped from *eclipse* as well as under *service mgr*, `tomcat6w.exe` seems to be in running state.

### [image]

How `tomcat6w.exe`different from `javaw.exe` from functionality aspect?

*J2EE beginner*

Answer (score 0):

`javaw.exe` is a part of the Java Virtual Machine. Specifically, it's one of the wrapper programs around the main JVM.

`tomcat6w.exe` is a service configuration editor for Tomcat. You can use it to modify the parameters for how the Windows Service behaves when it is launched: things like heap parameters and any other arguments you want to be able to add to the JVM's command-line when it launches. You can quit `tomcat6w.exe` anytime you like and it will not take-down your server.

Either you or Eclipse has launched the Tomcat Service Manager and you just aren't seeing it for some reason. It usually will have an icon in the system tray if you can't see an open window on the screen.

Comment: So what's the question? I think I've answered your original one already.